# Inclusion Exclusion for Two Separate Events

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

The following is a question from "A First Course in Probably $9^{th}$ Edition" Question 4 from the Section 2 Self Study.

Let $A$ denote the event that the midtown temperature
in Los Angeles is $70^◦F$, and let $B$ denote the event that
the midtown temperature in New York is $70^◦F$. Also, let
$C$ denote the event that the maximum of the midtown
temperatures in New York and in Los Angeles is $70^◦F$. If
$P(A) = .3$,$P(B) = .4$, and $P(C) = .2$, find the probability
that the minimum of the two midtown temperatures is
$70^◦F$.

The solution did the following:

Let $D$ be the even that the minimum temperature is $70^◦F$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) \\ 
P(C \cup D) = P(C) + P(D) - P(C\cap D)
\end{align}
$$

Then we fill in what we know:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A \cup B) = 0.3 + 0.4 - P(A\cap B) \\ 
P(C \cup D) = 0.2 + P(D) - P(C\cap D)
\end{align}
$$

And then the author throws something out there that I cannot justify:

$$
\text{Since }P(A \cup B) = P(C \cup D) \\
\text{and } P(A \cap B) = P(C \cap D)
$$

How do we know that these two are equal? I have not the slightest idea of why this would be true. Is it because $P( A \cup B) = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what $A, B, C, D$ actually mean. $A \cup B$ is the event "A or B", i.e. that at least one of the temperatures is $70^◦F$. $C \cup D$ is the event that either the maximum temperature or the minimum temperature is $70^◦F$. These two statements have exactly the same meaning. Same for $A \cap B$ and $C \cap D$; they both denote the event that both temperatures are $70^◦F$.